# Executing current Python script in Emacs on Windows

Tags: python, emacs

I've just started learning Emacs, and decided to start writing Python in it. I tried using C-c C-c to execute the current buffer, but I get the message `Searching for program: no such file or directory, python`.

I've looked on google, but I'm none the wiser as to how to sort this out (bear in mind I know next to nothing about Emacs!)

Comment: There is probably an environment variable you need to set up (maybe PYTHONPATH) or an emacs variable (maybe just PATH?) - http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_534.html. Try pointing your emacs path to wherever python is on your path.

Comment: Also, http://hide1713.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/setup-perfect-python-environment-in-emacs/, but I really have no idea what OS you're running...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to work it out, following the instructions [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonMode). I used python-mode.el, when before I had been using Emacs' built-in python.el, but according to [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonMode), "The version in Emacs 22 has a bunch of problems". Hope someone else running Emacs 22 on Windows XP finds this useful one day!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `C:\Python26` (or whatever Python you have installed) to the `PATH` environment variable.

I find [python-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonMode) and [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) to be useful for writing Python in emacs.